# SKLabelNode related EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, skspritenode, sklabelnode

Im currently having a crash which I can't find a solution for.

In the application I'm developing I have a custom class `LabelNode: SKNode` which uses a `SKLabelNode` and a `SKSpriteNode` to create white text on a black square background. This label is updated for every frame with new values with the `setText(newText: String)` function below

```
class LabelNode: SKNode {

private let textNode: SKLabelNode
private let backgroundNode: SKSpriteNode
private let padding: CGFloat

var width: CGFloat = 0
var height: CGFloat = 0
var horizontalAlignment = SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode.center

init(fontSize: CGFloat, text: String? = "A") {
    textNode = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Arial")
    textNode.zPosition = 1
    backgroundNode = SKSpriteNode(color: UIColor.black, size: CGSize(width: 0, height: 0))
    textNode.fontColor = UIColor.white
    textNode.fontSize = fontSize
    textNode.text = text
    textNode.verticalAlignmentMode = SKLabelVerticalAlignmentMode.top
    height = textNode.frame.size.height
    textNode.position.y = (height / 2)
    padding = 0.165 * height
    width = textNode.frame.size.width
    backgroundNode.size = CGSize(width: width + padding, height: height + padding)
    backgroundNode.position.x = textNode.frame.midX
    super.init()
    addChild(textNode)
    addChild(backgroundNode)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented for LabelNode")
}

func setText(newText: String) {
    self.textNode.text = newText
    width = self.textNode.frame.size.width
    backgroundNode.size = CGSize(width: width + padding, height: height + padding)
    backgroundNode.position.x = textNode.frame.midX
}

func setFontColor(newFontColor: UIColor) {
    self.textNode.fontColor = newFontColor
}

func setAlignment(newAlignment: SKLabelHorizontalAlignmentMode) {
    self.textNode.horizontalAlignmentMode = newAlignment
}
```

}

My application keeps throwing EXC_BAD_ACCESS with random time intervals, and sometimes with different error messages, and on different threads. Sometimes xcode points to the line

```
width = self.textNode.frame.size.width
```

but sometimes at random lines on Thread x but where the line above is active in thread y.

If zombies are activated but both `All Exceptions` breakpoint and `malloc_error_break` are deactivated I get the following terminal output on crash

```
-[SKTexture dealloc]: message sent to deallocated instance 0x10bbaf70
```

where `po 0x10bbaf70` only gives the output

```
280735600
```

and the following stack trace

```
* thread #41: tid = 0x73287, 0x1d9ac4d0 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 532, queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.applicationName.GameView0x1478d2b0', stop reason = EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=EXC_ARM_BREAKPOINT, subcode=0xdefe)
frame #0: 0x1d9ac4d0 CoreFoundation`___forwarding___ + 532
frame #1: 0x1d8d13d8 CoreFoundation`_CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 24
frame #2: 0x1cc25194 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_object::sidetable_release(bool) + 238
frame #3: 0x2b23ff0a SpriteKit`SKCSpriteNode::~SKCSpriteNode() + 38
frame #4: 0x2b23ff28 SpriteKit`SKCSpriteNode::~SKCSpriteNode() + 8
frame #5: 0x2b2204a2 SpriteKit`SKCLabelNode::rebuildText() + 134
frame #6: 0x2b2201b2 SpriteKit`SKCLabelNode::getBoundingBox() + 34
frame #7: 0x2b27d248 SpriteKit`-[SKNode frame] + 40
frame #8: 0x2b297928 SpriteKit`-[SKLabelNode frame] + 40
* frame #9: 0x000aea54 applicationName`LabelNode.setText(newText="9 555 m", self=0x15863970) -> () + 288 at LabelNode.swift:45
```

If i run with `All Exceptions` breakpoint and `malloc_error_break` activated I dont get any terminal output and the following stack trace

```
* thread #21: tid = 0x7414f, 0x1cc24612 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 2, queue = 'com.apple.scenekit.renderingQueue.applicationName.GameView0x177651b0', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x2)
frame #0: 0x1cc24612 libobjc.A.dylib`objc_release + 2
frame #1: 0x2b23fefa SpriteKit`SKCSpriteNode::~SKCSpriteNode() + 22
frame #2: 0x2b23ff28 SpriteKit`SKCSpriteNode::~SKCSpriteNode() + 8
frame #3: 0x2b2204a2 SpriteKit`SKCLabelNode::rebuildText() + 134
frame #4: 0x2b2201b2 SpriteKit`SKCLabelNode::getBoundingBox() + 34
frame #5: 0x2b27d248 SpriteKit`-[SKNode frame] + 40
frame #6: 0x2b297928 SpriteKit`-[SKLabelNode frame] + 40
* frame #7: 0x00181a54 applicationName`LabelNode.setText(newText="4 033 m", self=0x17786cb0) -> () + 288 at LabelNode.swift:45
```

Does anyone know what the reason behind this crash is or any further steps I can take to shed some light on this? Any tips would be very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't showed enough code to fully understand your problem, from what it looks like you are sub classing a labelNode and trying to place a spriteNode behind that label? This would be a much simpler situation in my opinion.

```
    class LabelNode : SKSpriteNode {

init(texture: SKTexture?, color: UIColor, size: CGSize, text: String) {

    super.init(texture: texture, color: color, size: size)


    let label = SKLabelNode(fontNamed: "Courier-Bold")
    label.fontSize = 50
    label.fontColor = SKColor.black
    label.position = CGPoint.init(x: 0.0, y: 0.0)
    label.zPosition = 1
    label.verticalAlignmentMode = .center
    label.text = text
    self.addChild(label)

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

       }
```

Create a custom sprite node class and add a label directly onto it.

Then add it to the view.

```
      let labelNode = LabelNode(texture: nil, color: .white, size: CGSize.init(width: 400, height: 100) , text: "Enter text")
    labelNode.position = CGPoint(x: self.frame.midX, y: self.frame.midY)

    self.addChild(labelNode)
```